# Encoding Urls C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, url, url-routing

So I have a URL that looks like this

```
http://www.test.com/folder1/id=3
```

But basically when they click the button, in the URL bar i want to display the name of the value associated with that id, for instance id=3 is a watch named "Rollex"

so I want the URL to read

```
http>//www.test.com/folder1/Rollex
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Need much more info.. where are you finding the information about which ID equals which product? How would I know that ID=3 is equivalent to Rollex (or even Rolex)?

Answer (score 8):

You should look up *URL Routing*, its exactly what you want. See [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

Comment: + 1: considering he's using the correct version, framwework and api.

Comment: For the extra points, you should also check out Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite. When you change a website say from asp to aspx search engines will still link to the asp. By using ISAPI rewrite you can specify a bunch of regEx's so requests to the asp pages map to the aspx equivilents.

Answer (score 1):

You need Url [Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

A rewrite engine is software that modifies a web URL's appearance (URL rewriting). Rewritten URLs (sometimes known as short, fancy URLs, or search engine friendly - SEF) are used to provide shorter and more relevant-looking links to web pages.

The technique adds a degree of separation between the files used to generate a web page and the URL that is presented to the World.

This blog post summarizes a few approaches you can take to cleanly map or rewrite URLs with ASP.NET, and have the option to structure the URLs of your application however you want.